How to solve the issue with getting free ports in Pytorch DDP?
I am facing issues with getting a free port in the DDP setup block of PyTorch for parallelizing my deep learning training job across multiple GPUs on a Linux HPC cluster.
I am trying to submit a deep learning training job to a Linux HPC cluster using a SLURM script. The training requires parallelization of the model and data across 4 GPUs. I am using the Distributed Data Parallel (DDP) module of PyTorch for distribution of the model and data across 4 GPUs. I have defined the DDP setup block as follows:
def ddp_setup(rank, world_size):
"""
Args:
    rank: Unique identifier of each process
    world_size: Total number of processes
"""
try:
    # Find a free port dynamically
    def find_free_port():
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind(('', 0))
            s.listen(1)
            port = s.getsockname()[1]
        return port

    # Destroy any existing process groups
    if dist.is_initialized():
        dist.destroy_process_group()

    # Set environment variables with a dynamic port
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    master_port = find_free_port()
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = str(master_port)

    # Initialize process group with additional error handling
    init_process_group(
        backend="nccl",
        rank=rank,
        world_size=world_size,
        timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
        init_method='env://'
    )

    # Set the GPU device
    torch.cuda.set_device(rank)

    print(f"Process group initialized successfully for rank {rank}")

except RuntimeError as e:
    print(f"Error initializing process group: {e}")
    # Provide more specific error handling
    if "Address already in use" in str(e):
        print("Port is already in use. Ensure no previous processes are running.")
    raise

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Unexpected error in ddp_setup: {e}")
    raise

But the issue which I am getting each time while running the code is that, the allotted port is showing as "already in use" whatever may be its number. I have attached the error block below:
[W socket.cpp:426] [c10d] The server socket has failed to listen on [::]:12356 (errno: 98 - Address already in use).
[W socket.cpp:426] [c10d] The server socket has failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:12356 (errno: 98 - Address already in use).
[E socket.cpp:462] [c10d] The server socket has failed to listen on any local network address.
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/scratch/j20240138/final_rdnet.py", line 401, in mp.spawn(main, args=(world_size, args.save_every, args.total_epochs, args.batch_size), nprocs=world_size), ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 239, in spawn return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 197, in start_processes while not context.join(): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 160, in join raise ProcessRaisedException(msg, error_index, failed_process.pid) torch.multiprocessing.spawn.ProcessRaisedException: -- Process 0 terminated with the following error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 69, in _wrap fn(i, *args) File "/scratch/j20240138/final_rdnet.py", line 369, in main ddp_setup(rank, world_size) File "/scratch/j20240138/final_rdnet.py", line 195, in ddp_setup init_process_group(backend="nccl", rank=rank, world_size=world_size, timeout=timedelta(minutes=60)) File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 900, in init_process_group store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous_iterator) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 245, in _env_rendezvous_handler store = _create_c10d_store(master_addr, master_port, rank, world_size, timeout) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 176, in _create_c10d_store return TCPStore( ^^^^^^^^^ RuntimeError: The server socket has failed to listen on any local network address. The server socket has failed to listen on [::]:12356 (errno: 98 - Address already in use). The server socket has failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:12356 (errno: 98 - Address already in use). srun: error: gpu010: task 0: Exited with exit code 1 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/scratch/j20240138/final_rdnet.py", line 401, in mp.spawn(main, args=(world_size, args.save_every, args.total_epochs, args.batch_size), nprocs=world_size), ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 239, in spawn return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 197, in start_processes while not context.join(): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 160, in join raise ProcessRaisedException(msg, error_index, failed_process.pid) torch.multiprocessing.spawn.ProcessRaisedException: -- Process 0 terminated with the following error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 69, in _wrap fn(i, *args) File "/scratch/j20240138/final_rdnet.py", line 369, in main ddp_setup(rank, world_size) File "/scratch/j20240138/final_rdnet.py", line 195, in ddp_setup init_process_group(backend="nccl", rank=rank, world_size=world_size, timeout=timedelta(minutes=60)) File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 932, in init_process_group _store_based_barrier(rank, store, timeout) File "/home/j20240138/miniconda3/envs/projenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 469, in _store_based_barrier raise RuntimeError( RuntimeError: Timed out initializing process group in store based barrier on rank: 0, for key: store_based_barrier_key:1 (world_size=2, worker_count=3, timeout=1:00:00) srun: error: gpu010: task 1: Exited with exit code 1
I need help in resolving this issue.

Have you tried to find the ports already in use and try to kill the processes on those ports? Of course, check if you need them... For example, you may be able to use lsof -i :<the-port> to find the processes that are using your port, and then kill -9 <process-id-that-is-the-PID-that-appears-when-you-use-lsof>. From the terminal of course

Yes I used lsof -i  :. But that doesn't give any output. So as per my understanding, it means that there are actually no processes that are using the port.
